# Ionic Firebase need to convert nested array

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework

I am tring to insert data in firebase. But the problem is its showing the nested data error. How can i convert nested array to simple array so i can put in firebase ?

Here is my .ts code

```
  create() {
    this.checked.push(this.user.userId);
    if(this.Name == ""){
      this.toast.show('Please give a group name');
    }
    else{
     // the user details are updated in firebase user list
     this.groupDetails = {
       groupname: this.Name,
       description: this.description || '',
       members: this.checked,
       messages: [],
       createdId: this.user.userId,
       createrName: this.user.username
     }
     console.log(this.groupDetails);
  // details are submitted to creatGroup function from groupProvider
      this.messageService.createGroup(this.groupDetails).then(resp => {
        console.log(resp);
        this.toast.show("Group Created");
        this.router.navigate(["/home"]);
      });
  }
}
 addCheckbox(event, checkbox : String, userName : String) {
   console.log(event);
    if ( event.detail.checked ) {
      this.checked.push([{member_id:checkbox, member_name:userName}]);
      console.log(this.checked);


    } else {
      let index = this.removeCheckedFromArray(checkbox);
      this.checked.splice(index,1);
    }
  }

  //Removes checkbox from array when you uncheck it
  removeCheckedFromArray(checkbox : String) {
    return this.checked.findIndex((category)=>{
      return category === checkbox;
      console.log(this.checked);
    })
  }
```

And my html code is this

```
<ion-content >


    <ion-item>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Group Name" class="custom-input"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div class="spacer" style="height: 5px;"></div>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-textarea type="text" row="8" [(ngModel)]="description" name="description" placeholder="Group Description" class="custom-input"></ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let usr of usersList"  >
          <ion-label>{{usr.username}}</ion-label>
          <ion-checkbox slot="start" (ionChange)="addCheckbox($event,usr.userId, usr.username)"></ion-checkbox>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>


</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
  <ion-button expand="block" class="g-btn"  (click)="create()">Create Group</ion-button>
</ion-footer>
```

The problem is causing in memebrs array. I have attach the screenshot of console how the members array look like i think need to change this array in simple array ?

[image]